# Highcharts columns length is not proportional

Tags: c#, jquery, highcharts

I am created stacked column charts using highcharts for handling large variation of data i am using my custom logarithmic functions.its working fine but there is issue with charts hights its not noticeable.

```
 function calcLog(val) {
  return (val > 0) ? Math.log(val * Math.E) : null;
}

function calcAntiLog(val) {
return (val > 0) ? Math.round(Math.exp(val) / Math.E) : null;
}


 function calcTotalAntiLog(valMatrix, idx) {
 if (valMatrix) {
    sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < valMatrix.length; i++) {
        sum += calcAntiLog(valMatrix[i][idx]);
    }
    return sum;
  }
return "";
}


 function calcTotalAntiLog2(hcObj) {
  if (hcObj) {
    var idx = hcObj.x;
    sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < hcObj.axis.chart.series.length; i++) {
        sum += calcAntiLog(hcObj.axis.chart.series[i].yData[idx]);
    }
    return sum;
  }
   return null;
 }


function das(hcObj) {
  if (hcObj) {
    var idx = hcObj.x;
      sum = 0;
    zeroVisits = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < hcObj.axis.chart.series.length; i++) {
        sum += calcAntiLog(hcObj.axis.chart.series[i].yData[idx]);
        if (i == 0) zeroVisits = sum;
    }
    return (100 * (sum - zeroVisits)) / sum;
}
return null;
}
```

Please refer  http://jsfiddle.net/rutup/6hxPU/26/

Comment: When displaying in labels true values it works as expected, see: http://jsfiddle.net/6hxPU/28/ - (5.83 vs 6.30). How otherwise it should be displayed?

Comment: @PawełFus thanks but i want to do some some changes with its height. So it becomes noticeable

Comment: So change your formula for calculating values.

Comment: you mean my functions like calclog and all?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Highcharts is displaying dat as you passed on, so I wouldn't expect different behavior.

Comment: i am using it because of large data. In case of large data lets say one has 1000 and another has 3 smaller data is being ignored and it doesn't display any chart for column having 3 as data

Comment: How about logarithmic axis? Won't that suit your needs?